# Action bar icon doesn't show icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to display a custom icon in the `ActionBar`, but it doesn't work.
I've tried it both programmatically with

```
 getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.forum_logo);
```

and

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.forum_logo);
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml with

```
android:logo="@drawable/forum_logo"
```

However, none of the two works. forum_logo.png is an image file of 24x24.

Other methods such as

```
 getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setTitle((currentSubforum.getTitle()));
```

works as intended.

I'm using `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` and each `Activity` extends `ActionBarActivity`.
The `android:icon` attribute in AndroidManifest is already linked at a different drawable and the `android:theme` is `"Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`

Comment: You mean up navigation icon? (left-hand side)?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html figure 1 point 1

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Comment: @Ragnar why you have deleted your answer? I'm trying to use the toolbar as you mentioned (yes, I'm waiting for gradle :S ). EDIT: doesn't work by the way, it ends up with an error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer with the Toolbar was correct, however was missing one crucial detail.

If you use a Toolbar, your theme must have the `ActionBar` disabled. There's a specific theme for that:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Now in your `onCreate` set the Toolbar like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Note that you should use the support Toolbar: `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;`

The Toolbar in your layout would look like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:background="#40ffffff"/>
```

---

That being said, I found it really weird not being able to display the app icon with `ActionBarActivity`. *Hopefully* there's another way around this.

Comment: I'll test it in a while. However, what I'm thinking is: using this toolbar, can I call `getSupportActionBar()` from other Activities?

Comment: It ends up with an error; actually, it seems that (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar) returns null. Is the xml correct as it is?

Comment: @tigerjack89 no way it would return null if you added it to your activity's layout and called `setContentView`

Comment: @tigerjack89 to answer the previous comment: you can't, since a toolbar is a part of an activity. Same with `ActionBar`, only you would inflate it at `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Comment: Sorry, my fail, I added the toolbar in a separate xml file. Now,  the workaround works as intended. However, the main problem with this approach is that I can't use the standard methods anymore. I mean, when I used the old ActionBar (even if without an icon), I can change it's title every time when switching to a new Activity; now, it obv returns a NullPointerException. Still a +1 because it works in some way, but I'm hoping for a better solution.

Comment: @tigerjack89 you can still do that. In `onCreateOptionsMenu` will be called when activity is newly created, so `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` there and perhaps set a title. Later you can call `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");` if not null.

Comment: Nott sure that I've fully understood your comment. I mean, I'm invoking `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` in the `onCreate()` method of `LoginActivity`. When this activity launch a new activity X, in `X.onCreate()` I'm invoking `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title")`; at this point, it raise a NullPointerException. What do I have to change and why?

Comment: @tigerjack89 as I've said every activity's layout must implement a Toolbar. It was the case with ActionBar too but it was done implicitly. Let's just wait for another answer (this is interesting to me too) if this is too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

After Fragment.onActivityCreated(...) you'll have a valid activity accessible through getActivity(). You'll need to cast it to an ActionBarActivity then make the call to getSupportActionBar().

((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(R.string.subtitle);
You do need the cast. It's not poor design it's backwards compatibility.

Comment: Ive tried this. I use a library to get an Icon and Title at the same time.

Comment: YOu can try: ActionsContentViewLib

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); 
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_video);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Only use 3 things..

Comment: Is all of these necessary if I want to display only an icon?

Comment: Error: `getActionBar`.

Comment: ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_video);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

Comment: I'm testing it... waiting for gradle to build :S

Comment: which activity you use? ActionBarActivity of Activity?

Comment: nothing, it just displays the activity with the right ActionBar title, but without any icon

Comment: then don't know, I use this in my activity and it works fine for me. and my activity extends Activity..

Answer (score 0):

in the manifest use your costume theme.

```
<application
        android:name="com.example.ifis.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ifis_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
```

customize your theme in the style folder as below and add your icon to the `icon`

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/ifisGreen</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/your_logo</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/ifisGreen</item>
        <item name="android:height">30dp</item>        
    </style>
```

Comment: Holo is not compatible with `ActionBarActivity`.